# What is the best way to list elements without mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, object

```
    var cities = [
    {"name":"About","link":"/","flag":"international"},
    {"name":"Buenos Aires","link":"buenos-aires","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"La Plata","link":"la-plata","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"Cologne","link":"cologne","flag":"germany"},
    {"name":"London","link":"london","flag":"unitedkingdom"},
    {"name":"Montreal","link":"montreal","flag":"canada"},
    {"name":"Melbourne","link":"melbourne","flag":"australia"}
    ];
```

I want to do a simple for each statement that lists out each city:

```
    <a href="link" class="flag">name</a>
```

am I set up properly?

so far, I am using the approach of @R3tep

```
var cities = [
    {"name":"Melbourne","link":"melbourne","flag":"australia"},
    {"name":"Montreal","link":"montreal","flag":"canada"},
    {"name":"London","link":"london","flag":"unitedkingdom"},
    {"name":"Cologne","link":"cologne","flag":"germany"},
    {"name":"La Plata","link":"la-plata","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"Buenos Aires","link":"buenos-aires","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"About","link":"/","flag":"international"}
];
    var city = "";
    for(var i = cities.length; i--;){
    city = city + "<div class='form-body'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-sm-12'><a title='Find Language Exchange Events in "+cities[i].name+"' href='"+cities[i].link+"'><div class='city_wrapper'><img class='clip sprite_cities_"+cities[i].flag+"' alt='Language Exchange in "+cities[i].name+" - Mundo Lingo' src='images/international/mundo-lingo-language-exchange-page-elements.png'/><span class='title'>"+cities[i].name+"</span></div></a></label></div></div>";
}
document.getElementById("city-demo").innerHTML = city;
```

It works perfectly, so thank you @Retep. I see in the future, a file getting larger once more cities are added, and was hoping to put this array in json format, and include it later, as well as being able to export from an excel sheet. Could var cities = @.json file import?

Comment: You're good to go. There is no "best way", but that seems like the most intuitive way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using the open source project http://www.jinqJs.com
 [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/fob56Lkc/)

```
 var cities = [
    {"name":"About","link":"/","flag":"international"},
    {"name":"Buenos Aires","link":"buenos-aires","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"La Plata","link":"la-plata","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"Cologne","link":"cologne","flag":"germany"},
    {"name":"London","link":"london","flag":"unitedkingdom"},
    {"name":"Montreal","link":"montreal","flag":"canada"},
    {"name":"Melbourne","link":"melbourne","flag":"australia"}
    ];

jinqJs().from(cities).select( function(row) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="' + row.link + '">' + row.name + '</a><br>';
});
```

Comment: pretty neat mysql substitute. if I kept all my information in an excel spreadsheet, and exported it as json to put in a file forder, could I use jingJs to access the json?

Comment: Yes, as long as the the JSON file can be accessed via http

Comment: thank you for that. my true aim is to keep javascript files down to a minimum size, gzipped, compressed, the works, etc. so, in your example with the code, i would not have a var cities. i would simply write jinqJs().from("http://site(dot)com/folder/file.json").select( function(row){document....})

Comment: Correct. The minified version is at https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.min.js and the GitHub project with all the API documentation is at https://github.com/fordth/jinqJs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template function you can use if you're doing a lot of lists.

listItems:

```
function listItems(arr, tpl, encode) {
  var html = "";

  var entities = {
    '"': "&quot;",
    '<': "&lt;",
    '>': "&gt;",
    //'/': "&#47;",
    '&': "&amp;",
    "'": "&#39;"
  };


  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    html += tpl.replace(/\:\w+/g, function(m){
      var value = item[m.substr(1)] || m;
      if (encode) { 
        value = value.replace(/["<>\/'&]/g,function(m){
          return entities[m] || m;
        });
      }
      return value;
    });
  }
  return html;
}
```

example:

```
var cities = [
    {"name":"About","link":"/","flag":"international"},
    {"name":"Buenos Aires","link":"buenos-aires","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"La Plata","link":"la-plata","flag":"argentina"},
    {"name":"Cologne","link":"cologne","flag":"germany"},
    {"name":"London","link":"london","flag":"unitedkingdom"},
    {"name":"Montreal","link":"montreal","flag":"canada"},
    {"name":"Melbourne","link":"melbourne","flag":"australia"}
    ];

var cityLink = '<a href=":link" class=":flag">:name</a>\n';
var html = listItems(cities, cityLink, true);
console.log(html);
```

Output:

```
<a href="/" class="international">About</a>
<a href="buenos-aires" class="argentina">Buenos Aires</a>
<a href="la-plata" class="argentina">La Plata</a>
<a href="cologne" class="germany">Cologne</a>
<a href="london" class="unitedkingdom">London</a>
<a href="montreal" class="canada">Montreal</a>
<a href="melbourne" class="australia">Melbourne</a>
```

Comment: "simple for each statement", I don't see the simple approach in your code

Comment: @R3tep it's a matter of perspective. The template is easier to change. I could have left out HTML encoding but now it's general purpose and not tied to the given data set.

Comment: wow, this approach looks powerful. I'm sure moving forward I'll have many more properties of each city. if i kept all my data in a spreadsheet and exported to json, could i import the json into the var cities?

Comment: @user1692959 Any key that is a word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ will match :keyname in the template.  You can add as many keys as you need to.